# Example of a translation unit vs file scope

Tags: c

Taking the following program as an example:

```
// myprogram.c
#include<stdio.h>
int a, b;
int main(void)
{
    printf("A: %d\n", a);
    printf("B: %d\n", b);
}
```

```
// friendsprogram.c
int a=1;
static int b=2;
```

```
$ gcc myprogram.c friendsprogram.c -o out; ./out
```

> A: 1 
> B: 0

How would the translation units be classified in the above?  And how what that be different than just the contents of the file "myprogram.c" and "friendsprogram.c"? Does the translation unit ever depend on the command that is issued to the compiler? For example, If I change the command to just:

```
$ gcc myprogram.c -o out; ./out
```

My output becomes:

> A: 0 
> B: 0

Comment: Try `‐fno-common`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart what you want to elaborate on that a bit, showing the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **translation unit** is a source file along with all of its included headers that is compiled as a single unit.

In this example, myprogram.c along with the header stdio.h is one translation unit.  The file friendsprogram.c is another translation unit.

Note that this doesn't change when you compile like this:

```
gcc myprogram.c friendsprogram.c -o out
```

Because this command line combines *compiling* and *linking* into a single step.  A temporary object file is created for myprogram.c and another for friendsprogram.c, then those object files are linked to create the file "out".

Comment: is there a way to only do the compiling, and not the linking with gcc? And if so, would it have one output file for each input file, or how would that work?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 An example of separate compiling and linking would be `gcc -c myprogram.c ; gcc -c friendsprogram.c ; gcc myprogram.o friendsprogram.o -o out`

Comment: got it, thank you. So basically a "translation unit" is all that would go into the object file if that C source file were compiled independently, correct?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Correct

Comment: Note that the compiler has no clue whether something is a header file or not - it's all just files. This means "myprogram.c" can do `#include "friendsprogram.c"`  (or "friendsprogram.c" can do `#include "myprogram.c"`) to put everything the same translation unit . This can be abused to get better optimization (e.g. make most functions `static` and end up with something like whole program optimization without using link-time optimization).

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is a side effect of old lenient compiler/linker behavior and a so-called "common" section.

```
int a;
```

The C spec says this global-scope variable is initialized to zero. You would expect this to go into the `.bss` (zero-initialized data) section of the executable.

But in GCC <10, the variable is put into the "common" section when that file (translation unit) is compiled.

```
int a=1;
```

Now you've provided an initialization, and this variable will go into the `.data` section.

But when the linker links these two object files together, rather than issue a "multiple definitions" (for the same name) error, it will do something controversial, and *merge them* into one variable, due to the common section semantics.

By passing `-fno-common`, or using GCC >= 10, the common section is not used, and the linker will issue an error and refuse to link your program.

---

So what *should* you do? Simple: provide only one definition for any name.

If you really want to use global variables (undesirable in general), and you want to put them in a separate translation unit (weird), use  `extern` in your other files:

**`data.h`**

```
// Declaration: Tells everyone that 'a' exists somewhere
extern int a;
```

**`data.c`**

```
#include "data.h"

// Definition: defines the variable and its initial value
int a = 42;
```

**`main.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "data.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
}
```